# Referenced library not pushed

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am currently working on eclipse, my project gets pushed but referenced jar file does not get pushed. There used to be a message that comes up saying what will be pushed but is no longer showing up how can I push the referenced library

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.gitignore` file.

I guess `.gitignore` don't allow you push `*.jar` file(s) to GitHub repository.(Everyone usually do this. Best practice is don't commit/push jar file,use Maven or Gradle build system/dependency manager)